# Why are my precision-recall and ROC curves not smooth?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I have some data labeled as either a 0 or 1 and I am trying to predict these classes using a random forest. Each instance is labeled with 20 features that are used to train the random forest (~30.000 training instances and ~6000 test instances.

I am plotting the precision-recall and ROC curves using the following code:

```
precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_pred)
plt.step(recall, precision, color='b', alpha=0.2,where='post')
plt.fill_between(recall, precision, step='post', alpha=0.2, color='b')

fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
```

All the PR and ROC curves I have seen thus far always have a jagged/smooth decline in precision/recall and a smooth/jagged increase in the ROC line. But my PR and ROC curves for some reason always look like this:

[image: PR curve]
[image: ROC curve]
For some reason the only have a single point where they change direction. Is this due to a coding error by me or something inherent about the data/classification problem? If so, how can this behavior be explained?

Comment: Is your `y_pred` probabilies of the target class or the actual predicted class?

Comment: See my answer and let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you used the RandomForestClassifier.predict() method which results in either 0 or 1 depending on the predicted class.

To get the probability, which is the fraction of trees voted for a specific class, you have to use the RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba() method.

Using these probabilities as input for your curve calculations should fix the problem.

EDIT: The curve creation methods of scikit-learn sort the predictions first according to the prediction score, then according to their real/observed value, therefore the curves have these "bends".

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, silly mistake. Curves look beautiful now :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `precision_recall_curve`, the `y_pred` must be the `probabilities` of the target class **AND NOT** the actual predicted class.

Since you are using a `RandomForestClassifier`, use [predict_proba(X)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) to get the probabilities.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
probas_pred = rf.predict_proba(X_test)

precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_true, probas_pred)
plt.step(recall, precision, color='b', alpha=0.2,where='post')
plt.fill_between(recall, precision, step='post', alpha=0.2, color='b')
```