# How to smooth a ROC curve from binary data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, roc

I am trying to create a smooth ROC curve using the attached sample dataset. My code is working fine and generated ROC and AUROC. But my issue is the curve is not smooth [check the below image for details]. My prediction values are binaries and not probability values. This is the main reason for this type of curve.  I tried to smooth my curve based on some approaches proposed in [[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330955/how-to-smooth-roc-curve), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423494/why-are-my-precision-recall-and-roc-curves-not-smooth), [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057084/roc-curve-looks-too-sharp-and-not-smooth)], But I failed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.metrics import *
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


Raw_data = pd.read_csv("testing.csv",sep=',',header=0)
y_preds = Raw_data.drop(["y_test"], axis=1)
y_test = Raw_data["y_test"]
x= y_preds.iloc[:,[0]];
plt.figure(figsize=(14,10),dpi=640)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_preds.iloc[:,[0]])
auc1 = auc(fpr,tpr)

plt.plot(fpr, tpr,label="AUROC: {0}".format(auc1),color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=1) 
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0]) 
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])

plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')  
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate') 
plt.title('ROC') 
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Data sample:

```
y_test = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

```
y_pred = y_test = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
```

**`N.B. I don't have access to raw data and cannot use predict_proba()`**

[image]

Comment: As your three linked questions all say, you cannot draw the ROC curve without a meaningful confidence measure (usually predicted probabilities).